# StaticMapPlugin not loading in gazebo11

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I tried using the static map plugin following the tutorial in http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=static_map_plugin&cat=build_world

However, the plugin doesn't load properly.

```
[Err] [Plugin.hh:178] Failed to load plugin libStaticMapPlugin.so: libStaticMapPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25238/staticmapplugin-not-loading-in-gazebo11/) by [Jaeyoung-Lim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24627/jaeyoung-lim/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Actually, this was because I didn't source the environment properly.

Fixed by

```
source /usr/share/gazebo-11/setup.sh
```

---

Originally posted by [Jaeyoung-Lim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24627/jaeyoung-lim/) with karma: 1 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0